# how to use php $_GET variable with unicode characters?

Tags: php, jquery, unicode

```
<div class="linkL">STRAŠNI MIKROSKOP</div>
<?php
    $chapter = "chapters/" . $_GET["ch"] . ".php";
    include $chapter;
?>
```

js

```
$(".linkL").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).html();
    var b = a.split(' ').join('-');
    var c = b.toLowerCase();
    location.href = "index.php?ch=" + c;
});
```

after click in address bar I have `index.php?ch=strašni-mikroskop`. That's ok, but the file `chapters/strašni-mikroskop` is not included !?

If I replace `š` with `s` - everything works.

So, how can I use the above code using `š` unicode character ?

All files are encoded as utf8.

Comment: Try `$chapter = rawurlencode("chapters/" . $_GET["ch"] . ".php");`

Comment: @Michel, thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It could be your server doesn't like those special characters in file- and folder-names. Try to hardcode the link in your js (`location.href = "index.php?ch=strašni-mikroskop";`) If it still doesn't work, it's probably the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href = "index.php?ch=" + c;
```

You need to `encodeURIComponent(c)` here. Otherwise, any characters that are special in a URL, like `%` or `&`, will break the URL. Also this ensures the encoding used in the URL is UTF-8; without the explicit encoding it is up to the browser what happens and you may get inconsistent results.

```
$chapter = "chapters/" . $_GET["ch"] . ".php";
include $chapter;
```

Problem 1: the encoding of the filename needs to be the same as the encoding in the URL. That means you need to configure your file transfer tool to use UTF-8 (how you do this depends on the tool). If your server is Windows you can't use UTF-8 so you have to deliberately mis-encode your filenames. (eg for a Western European server it would use code page 1252, in which case you would have to mis-spell your file `straÅ¡ni-mikroskop.php`.)

It is probably not worth trying to do this as it is fragile and will break when you move to different tools and servers.

Problem 2: this is security hole. An attacker can supply arbitrary relative pathnames like `../someotherdirectory/x` to execute files you did not expect. That might combine with other features like file upload to give an attacker the ability to execute arbitrary code on your server. Or one could just include `index.php` itself to get an infinite loop and DoS your server.

You might avoid both these problems with a safe encoding scheme. For example with `bin2hex(c)` you could call your file `73747261c5a16e692d6d696b726f736b6f70.php` which would work anywhere and avoid path-special characters like `/`.

But it is in general best not to allow a user to pick an arbitrary PHP file. Usually better to have a static list of possibilities in the script; then you can call your files what you like. eg

```
switch ($_GET['ch']) {
    case 'strašni-mikroskop': include 'chapters/strasni-mikroskop.php'; break;
    case '☃':                 include 'chapters/snowman.php';           break;
    ...
}
```

Problem 3. Marking up links with a `<div>` is pretty bad for accessibility, usability, and SEO. Why not just use normal `<a>` links?